# Rotating text of secondary axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm taking advantage of the recently added feature of secondary axis labels in ggplot2.  I'd like to rotate *just* the secondary axis but have been unable to find documentation or work out how to do this.

Its simple enough to rotate all text using...

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, colour = mpg)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(name = 'Bottom Axis',
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~ .,
                                           name  = 'Top Axis',
                                           breaks = c(2:5),
                                           labels = c('Two Two', 'Three Three Three', 'Four Four Four Four', 'Five Five Five Five Five'))) +
## Rotate text of x-axis
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image: Example dual Axis plot with both axes labels rotated]
Its not mentioned in any of the documentation I've read (e.g. [scale_continuous](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html) and [themes](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html)) how to achieve rotating of just one axis.

My motivation for requiring this is that some of the labels I wish to apply to my data are long and overlap when placed horizontally, by rotating them I can avoid this, but I wish to retain the horizontal orientation on the bottom axis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as you have a relatively current version of `ggplot2`, you can use `axis.text.x.top`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, colour = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = 'Bottom Axis',
    sec.axis = sec_axis(
      trans = ~ .,
      name  = 'Top Axis',
      breaks = 2:5,
      labels = c('Two Two', 'Three Three Three', 'Four Four Four Four', 'Five Five Five Five Five')
    )
  ) +
  ## Rotate text of x-axis
  theme(axis.text.x.top = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution Axeman, I'd stumbled across that an hour ago and it works great in this simplified example but I'm now scratching my head as to why it doesn't work on my actual data.  Good to know I'm on the right track though, cheers.

Comment: Solved, order matters, I had a subsequent `+ theme()` applying to my plot which was scrubbing the `theme(axis.text.x.top = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0))` (added just in case anyone else forgets that order matters and subsequent calls to `theme()` can wipe previous calls).